# What was the meaning of "21 grams"?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, 21-grams

At the end of *21 Grams* (2003), the teller said, “They say we all loose 21 grams at the exact moment of our death.” I’m just interested in what that 21 grams means which caused the makers to entitle the movie *21 Grams*.

Comment: Essentially its a plot device based on a popular myth. Of course, there is no scientific evidence that a human soul exists. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/do-we-lose-7-pounds-when-we-die

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [Dr. Duncan MacDougall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_MacDougall_%28doctor%29) says,

> Dr. Duncan “Om” MacDougall (c. 1866 – October 15, 1920) was an early 20th-century physician in Haverhill, Massachusetts who sought to measure the mass lost by a human when the soul departed the body at death. MacDougall attempted to measure the mass change of six patients at the moment of death. His first subject, the results from which MacDougall felt were most accurate, lost “three-fourths of an ounce”, which has since been popularized as “21 grams”.

*21 Grams* is a 2003 American drama film which references the notion that the human soul has mass, more specifically that it weighs twenty-one grams.